# PyQt 4.8 Phenon.VideoPlayer wrong video state

Tags: python, linux, video, debian, pyqt4

While I was doing some python programming, I am newbie to PyQt. We use linux OS (debian) and PyQt 4.8 with python 2.7.

My task is to make it play video. I have researcvhed possibilities abit and decided to go for Phenon.VideoPlayer module.

After a while I have had working test script to play video file:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon


# CONST ****************************************************************************************************************

SAMPLE_VIDEO_LOCAL = 'Event-29544-r1-s1.mp4'

SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_MP4 = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'
SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_WEBM = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm'
SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_OGV = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv'
SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_3GP = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp'
SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_FLV = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.flv'


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
print "Showing VP"
vp.show()

print "Loading media"
media = Phonon.MediaSource(SAMPLE_VIDEO_LOCAL)
vp.load(media)
mo = vp.mediaObject()
media_state = mo.state()
while media_state == Phonon.LoadingState:
    media_state = mo.state()
    if media_state == Phonon.StoppedState:
        print "Ready to play"
        break
    elif media_state == Phonon.BufferingState:
        print "Buffering data from URL, please wait.."
    elif media_state == Phonon.ErrorState:
        print "Error has occured with media.."
        sys.exit()
    print "Loading.."

vp.setVolume(0.0)
print "Media loaded, playing.."
vp.play()
print "Finished, exitting!"
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this works as intended. But once I try to keep video running, detect when video has stopped and play it again, It fails to do so. Both approaches

```
while True:
    print vp.currentTime()
    if vp.isPlaying():
        print "It is playing.."
    else:
        print "Video stopped, playing it again.."
        vp.play()
    time.sleep(1)
```

and

```
while True:
    media_state = mo.state()
    if Phonon.PlayingState:
        continue
    elif media_state == Phonon.StoppedState:
        vp.play()
```

act like if the video is stopped, but it is not, as I see it running on my display, and the script just keeps starting them again and again and again..until I kill it. It does not matter if I play it form URL or local file, result is allways same.

Answer (score 0):

Basic rule of a GUI: you should not use blocking tasks in a GUI, in your case the `while True:` is, PyQt informs you of the status of certain variables through signals, in this case you should use the [`stateChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/phonon-mediaobject.html#stateChanged) signal of `Phonon::MediaObject`

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon


# CONST ****************************************************************************************************************

SAMPLE_VIDEO_LOCAL = 'Event-29544-r1-s1.mp4'

SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_MP4 = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'
SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_WEBM = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm'
SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_OGV = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv'
SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_3GP = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp'
SAMPLE_VIDEO_URL_FLV = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.flv'



def onStateChanged(newstate, oldState):
    if newstate == Phonon.StoppedState:
        print("Ready to play")
    elif newstate == Phonon.BufferingState:
        print("Buffering data from URL, please wait..")
    elif newstate == Phonon.ErrorState:
        print("Error has occured with media..")
        QtGui.QApplication.quit()
    print("Loading..")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
    vp.show()
    print("Loading media")
    media = Phonon.MediaSource(SAMPLE_VIDEO_LOCAL)
    vp.load(media)
    mo = vp.mediaObject()
    mo.stateChanged.connect(onStateChanged)
    vp.setVolume(0.0)
    print("Media loaded, playing..")
    vp.play()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```